# Demonstration of an arbitrarily oriented and translated ellipsoid

Tags: graphics, dynamic

(*Edited and modified*)
After the advice I received I modify the post.

I have created the following code for depicting an arbitrarily rotated and translated ellipsoid, along its ellipsoidal axes and cross sections:

```
(*Euler angles*)
Rx = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[γ], 
   Sin[γ]}, {0, -Sin[γ], Cos[γ]}}
Ry = {{Cos[β], 0, -Sin[β]}, {0, 1, 0}, {Sin[β], 0, 
   Cos[β]}}
Rz = {{Cos[α], Sin[α], 0}, {-Sin[α], 
   Cos[α], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
R[α_, β_, γ_] = Rx.Ry.Rz;

(*translation*)
OffsetTrans[d_, e_, f_] := {d, e, f};

(*parametric equations of arbitrarily rotated and translated ellipsoid*)
X0[x0_, y0_, z0_] := {x0, y0, z0};

XPar[θ_, ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] =
   R[α, β, γ].X0[x0, y0, z0] /. {x0 -> 
     a Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], y0 -> b Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
    z0 -> c Cos[ϕ]};

XParTrans[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] = 
  OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
   XPar[θ, ϕ, a, b, c, α, β, γ];

(*Ellipsoidal Axes*)
Cross0[a_, b_, c_] := {Line[{{-a, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}}], 
  Line[{{0, -b, 0}, {0, b, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0, -c}, {0, 0, c}}]}

CrossRot0[a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, \
γ].{-a, 0, 0}, R[α, β, γ].{a, 0, 0}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, -b, 0}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, b, 0}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, -c}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, c}}]}

CrossRotTrans[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, \
γ].{-a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}

CrossRotTransAlpha[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{-a,
        0, 0} + {d, e, f}, R[α, 0, 0].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, 0, 0].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, 0, 0].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}

CrossRotTransBetaAlpha[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, 
       0].{-a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, 0].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, 0].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, 0].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, 0].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, 0].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}

(*cross sections*)

CrossSectionX[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
   c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, b Cos[ϕ], 
      c Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Magenta}];

CrossSectionY[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
   c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
    R[α, β, γ].{a Cos[ϕ], 0, 
      c Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Pink}];

CrossSectionZ[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
   c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
    R[α, β, γ].{a Cos[ϕ], b Sin[ϕ], 
      0}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Purple}];

(*Altogether*)
Clear[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, EllipsoidalFun] 
EllipsoidalFun[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_, {opts___}] := 
 Module[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8},
  g2 = CrossRotTrans[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ];
  g3 = CrossSectionX[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
  g4 = CrossSectionY[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
  g5 = CrossSectionZ[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ];
  g6 = CrossRotTransAlpha[d, e, f, a, b, 
    c, α, β, γ]; 
  g7 = CrossRotTransBetaAlpha[d, e, f, a, b, 
    c, α, β, γ];
  g1 = ParametricPlot3D[
    XParTrans[d, e, f, a, b, 
     c, α, β, γ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {ϕ, 0,
      Pi}, PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]], 
    Mesh -> None];
  g8 = Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {d, e, f}}];
  Legended[
   Show[{g1, 
     Graphics3D[{{Gray, g8}, {Red, Thick, g6}, {Green, Thick, 
        g7}, {Blue, Thick, g2}}], g3, g4, g5}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Ticks -> None, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20, Bold], 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[Framed[
       "Arbitrarily Oriented & Translated Ellipsoid\nTranslation:\t\
d=" <> ToString[d] <> ",\te=" <> ToString[e] <> ",\tf=" <> 
        ToString[f] <> "\nRotations: \tα=" <> 
        ToString[TraditionalForm@α] <> ",\tβ=" <> 
        ToString[TraditionalForm@β] <> ",\tγ=" <> 
        ToString[TraditionalForm@γ] <> 
        "\nEllipsoidal Semi-Axes: \ta=" <> ToString[a] <> "\tb=" <> 
        ToString[b] <> "\tc=" <> ToString[c]], Blue, 20, 
      Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], opts], 
   LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Gray], 
     Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Green], 
     Directive[Thick, Blue]}, {Style["Global Coordinate System XYZ", 
      FontSize -> 18], 
     Style[
      "Translation by " <> 
       ToString[TraditionalForm[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*
StyleBox["d", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["X", "TI"], "^"] + \*
StyleBox["e", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["Y", "TI"], "^"] + \*
StyleBox["f", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["Z", "TI"], "^"]\)]], FontSize -> 18, Gray], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@α] <>
        " about Z–axis\nNew Coordinate System x'y'z'; z'\
≡Z", 18, Red], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@β] <>
        " about y'–axis\nNew Coordinate System x''y''z''; y\
''≡y'", 18, Green], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@γ] <>
        " about x''–axis\nFinal (Local) Coordinate System xyz; \
x≡x''", 18, Blue]}, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"]]]
```

(*Example*)

```
EllipsoidalFun[12, 21, 30, 4, 7, 25, Pi/4, Pi/3, Pi/6, {}]
```

[image: Output]

So I create the following Manipulate "object"

```
Manipulate[
 EllipsoidalFun[d, e, f, a, b, 
  c, α, β, γ, {}], {d, -10, 10, 1}, {e, -10, 10, 
  1}, {f, -10, 10, 1}, {a, 1, 10, 1}, {b, 1, 10, 1}, {c, 1, 100, 
  1}, {α, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, {β, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Pi/10}, {γ, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}]
```

[image: output]

Any ideas to make it better?
Also how I can put all the code inside Manipulate?
Is it possible instead of Manipulate to use a Dynamic environment so that the user will define the values of the parameters `d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ` ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at `Manipulate` already? As for the interactive thing, that will most likely only work with the player or browser plugin (unless you host it yourself via webMathematica).

Comment: Yes I know about Manipulate. But what I have done with it is very trivial. I would insist more:-)!

Comment: You could show what you´ve done already to give us an idea where you are stuck, otherwise as a pure coding request the question may not attract a lot of responses.

Comment: Yves thanks for the advice. I edited the post. It contains the best that I have done so far:-)!

Comment: Look into using `RotationTransform` and related instead of rolling your own.  Also I'd suggest providing initial values for `Manipulate`, eg, {{d,0},-10,10,1}`

Comment: @George: I would prefer to use my own equations if possible. The code will be used then by a student and I want him to see the equations I used. `RotationTransform` provides something that can be useful apart from making the code more attractive? Regarding the second hint I am taking into account right now!

Comment: just neater and maybe less prone to error.. `r[a_, b_, c_] = 
 Dot @@ MapThread[RotationMatrix, { -{ c, b, a}, IdentityMatrix[3]}]`.  Since its not a delayed assignment there will be no effect on performance.  Another small piece of advice, avoid starting your own symbols with Caps to avoid conflicts with built in functions.

Comment: I vote to leave open. The question is not too broad; it merely asks for code review.